# Are the components of a vector the coefficients in the general form of a linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have always understood vectors to be sets of numbers such that their components are coefficients in the general form of a linear equation. For example, take the vector $(2, 1)$. I would draw this in 2-dimensional space like so:

[image]

In other words, the first component is the coefficient for `x`, and the second component is the coefficient for `y`. This generalizes to n-dimensional space.

Where this falls apart is when I try to compute the slope of this line. Since I assume we are in general form:

$$
Ax + By + C = 0
$$
$$
2x + y + 0 = 0
$$
$$
y = -2x
$$

But that means that the slope of the line $m = -2$, which is:

[image]

I've tried this a few times, and it seems like the vector actually represents a line that is orthogonal to the one I had in mind. I feel like I'm going crazy or missing something really basic. What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Why are you conflating the vector $(2,1)$ and the line $2x+y=0$?  What makes you think they're the same object?

Comment: The slope of the line that is parallel to the vector $a=(2,1)$ and contains the point $A(2,1)$ is a line with slope $m=-\frac{1}{2}$. Since $y=mx+c$ , the only thing you need to do is to plug in the coordinates of A to get c.

Comment: @Bye_World, I don't know how to answer, "What makes you think..." That was my understanding. I guess because they look similar.

Comment: @gwg It's false.  They are two different things.  In fact, if you've gotten to the dot product and orthogonality, yet, you'll see that $2x+y=0$ is the same as $(2,1)\cdot(x,y)=0$ which says that the line is all the points *orthogonal* (perpendicular) to $(2,1)$, not parallel to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf v=(A,B)$ be your vector. The equation $Ax+By+C=0$ is equivalent to $\mathbf v\cdot(\mathbf x-\mathbf p)=0$, which says that $\mathbf v$ is *orthogonal* to the line, not parallel to it, just as you discovered. If you instead consider the line given parametrically by $\mathbf x=t\mathbf v+\mathbf p$, the slope will be $B/A$ as you expected, since this line is parallel to the vector.